# Choosing the latest record filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-dsl

this is my elasticsearch DSL filter that i'm using to get the latest record with the event.action=ssh_login and event.outcome=failure , but i get this error[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME])

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "event.action": "ssh_login"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "event.outcome": "failure"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"aggregations": {
  "last_event": {
    "top_hits": {
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "@timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
 }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole query?

And put this parameter on the `/_search` ?error_trace=true, then also please post the whole response